# How can I stop AWS Sam Typescript application EsBundleStep failing when I add a dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am trying to build an aws sam application using Typescript.

I wish to use the following node library https://www.npmjs.com/package/hanzi-tools.

However I cannot get it to work. Below is my lambda

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { Headers } from 'node-fetch';
var pinyinify = require("hanzi-tools").pinyinify;


type AnkiCardField = {
    value: string
}

type AnkiCardFields = {
    Front: AnkiCardField;
    Back: AnkiCardField;
    Pinyin: AnkiCardField;
}

type AnkiCard = {
    cardId: number;
    fields: AnkiCardFields;
}

function getListOfCards() {

    console.log(process.env.ANKI_CONNECT_URL);
    console.log(process.env.ANKI_CONNECT_PORT);
    let endpoint = 'http://' + process.env.ANKI_CONNECT_URL + ':' + process.env.ANKI_CONNECT_PORT;

    var requestHeaders = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var requestBody = JSON.stringify({ "action": "findCards", "version": 6, "params": { "query": "deck:TestDeck" } });
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: requestHeaders,
        body: requestBody
    };

    fetch(endpoint, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(ankiFindCardsResponse => {
            var cardIdArray = ankiFindCardsResponse.result;
            var cardInfoRequestBody = JSON.stringify({ "action": "cardsInfo", "version": 6, "params": { "cards": cardIdArray } });
            var cardInfoRequestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: requestHeaders,
                body: cardInfoRequestBody
            };
            return fetch(endpoint, cardInfoRequestOptions);
        })
        .then(cardInfoResponse => cardInfoResponse.json())
        .then(cardInfoResponseJson => {
            var ankiCardArray = cardInfoResponseJson.result;
            let singleCharacterMap = new Map<string, AnkiCard>();
            let multipleChararacterCards: AnkiCard[] = [];
            let singleCardCount = 0;
            let doubleCardCount = 0;
            console.log(`There are a total of ${ankiCardArray.length} cards`);

            ankiCardArray.forEach((ankiCard: AnkiCard) => {
                let chinese: string = ankiCard.fields.Front.value;
                if (chinese.length == 1) {
                    singleCharacterMap.set(chinese, ankiCard);
                    singleCardCount++;
                } else {
                    multipleChararacterCards.push(ankiCard);
                    doubleCardCount++;
                }
            });
            console.log(`There are a total of ${singleCardCount} single character cards`);
            console.log(`There are a total of ${doubleCardCount} double character cards`);


            multipleChararacterCards.forEach((multiCharacterCard: AnkiCard) => {
                let chinese: string = multiCharacterCard.fields.Front.value;
                chinese.split('').forEach(chineseCharacter => {
                    if (!singleCharacterMap.has(chineseCharacter)) {
                        //pinyinify(chineseCharacter);
                        console.log(`${chineseCharacter} needs to be added.`)
                    }
                });

            });
        }

        )
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));



}


export const lambdaHandler = (event: Object): String => {
    getListOfCards();
    return "Done";

};
```

The line

```
var pinyinify = require("hanzi-tools").pinyinify;
```

breaks the build. Whenever I run sam build after adding this line I get the following error:

```
    Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "mock-aws-s3"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:43:28:
      43 │     const AWSMock = require('mock-aws-s3');
         ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "mock-aws-s3" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "aws-sdk"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:76:22:
      76 │   const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
         ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "aws-sdk" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "nock"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:112:23:
      112 │   const nock = require('nock');
          ╵                        ~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "nock" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

If I mark the paths as external in the template.yaml the sam build step succeeds but then it fails at runtime. I am a bit lost.

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello world sample for NodeJS",
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/tree/develop/samcli/local/init/templates/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-nodejs",
  "author": "SAM CLI",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "unit": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint '*.ts' --quiet --fix",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "test": "npm run compile && npm run unit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.4",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
    "esbuild-jest": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.14.14",
    "hanzi-tools": "^1.2.26",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

The following is my template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  anki-connect-lambda

  Sample SAM Template for anki-connect-lambda

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
  AnkiConnectLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambda/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      MemorySize: 2048
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ANKI_CONNECT_URL : localhost
          ANKI_CONNECT_PORT: 8765
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
        - app.ts


  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: 'true'
    DependsOn: ApplicationResourceGroup
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  AnkiConnectLambda:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt AnkiConnectLambda.Arn
  AnkiConnectLambdaIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function
    Value: !GetAtt AnkiConnectLambdaRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I had to add nock, and mock-aws-s3 to my package dependencies, then sam build was able to succeed.

I'm not sure what the root cause of the issue is, and I don't like adding dependencies that I'm not using.. Hopefully someone else will have some better insight.